# Python program to connect to console via telnetlib

Tags: python, regex, list, python-2.7, telnet

Hi I am a tcl person trying to do a day to day activity in Python in order to get familiarity with a new language and to compare Python with tcl. No one wants tcl programs anymore :)

Ok , So I have come with a code to automate this typical activity I would do to clear a console line .

```
$ telnet 172.28.247.240
Trying 172.28.247.240...
Escape character is '^]'.
User Access Verification
Password: 
labc-f18-ts>en
Password: 
labc-f18-ts#clear line 66
[confirm]
 [OK]
```

My Code looks like this:

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

a_tuple = [ ('172.28.247.240' , 66)]
HOST = j[0]
user = "admin"
password = "1234"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")
    tn.read_until("labc-f18-ts>") 
    tn.write ("en" +"\n")
    tn.read_until("labc-f18-ts#")
    tn.write("clear line %d" %j[1])
    tn.write("exit\n")
    sess_op = tn.read_all()
    print sess_op
```

But I dont seem to get any output and dont know if it actually cleared the lines - there is no output whatsoever. Please help.

Also is there anything like `pexpect` that I should be working with rather what I have above?

Comment: Hi, I've fixed up some of the code as Python is white-space dependant, and the code sample you had wouldn't have been able to run.

Comment: Thanks @Lego But still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import telnetlib
# ...

a_tuple = [('172.28.247.240', 66)]
HOST = a_tuple[0] # do you mean to use 'a_tuple' instead of 'j'?
# ...

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST[0], HOST[1]) # <-- pass the port, I don't think this accepts tuples of hostname/ip and port
# ...
```

Should part of your code looks like above instead?

Also, I would normally use carriage return (\r) instead of new line (\n) when sending commands.  Some host are picky about this.

Comment: `HOST = ('172.28.247.240',66)` and then `tn = telnetlib.Telnet(*Host)` would be even slicker.